# how to create a table in dynamodb that is on-demand using python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, ondemand

I tried this way but I get the error Invalid type for parameter ProvisionedThroughput.ReadCapacityUnits, value: on-demand, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'int'>

`ProvisionedThroughput={ 'ReadCapacityUnits': 'on-demand', 'WriteCapacityUnits': 'on-demand' }`

Comment: If you don't set `ProvisionedThroughput` I believe you get on-demand

Comment: in the create_table() request use BillingMode='PAY_PER_REQUEST'   docs here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.create_table

Answer (score 5):

```
ddb.create_table(
    TableName='my_table',
    KeySchema=[
        {'AttributeName': 'id', 'KeyType': 'HASH'},
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {'AttributeName': 'id', 'AttributeType': 'S'},
    ],
    BillingMode='PAY_PER_REQUEST',
)
```